# Saving Strings from Firestore in an ArrrayList in Java

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently trying to create an app which asks a question and shows the answer. I'm saving those as documents on Firestore ( every document in the collection has a string for a question and another one for an answer).
I'm trying to read every document in that collection ( with a for loop? ) and then save the answer in one arrayList and the question in another one. I only get an Error Message, saying 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference'.

After clicking the continue Button:

```
QuestionView.setText(randomSpieler + ", " + Question);
```

Code in the function for saving the questions in a array list:

```
public void get_questions(){
    colref_QUESTIONS.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots){
                    String question = documentSnapshot.getString("question");
                    String answer = documentSnapshot.getString("answer");
                    questions.add(question);
                    answers.add(answer);
                    nrofquestions++;
                }
            }  
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you share your database structure?

Comment: please post the full code of where did you initialize questions and  answers list?

Comment: Is there something related to your code where you are trying to get something from a list? If yes, add it to your code. Are you sure that list is initialized? Please also respond with @AlexMam

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not defined one of the variables.Can you say which line contains error?

Comment: QuestionView.setText(randomSpieler + ", " + Question);    It seems like the ArrayList is empty. So I guess I didn't get any documents or I didn't add the strings to the arrayList the right way

Answer (score 0):

How are you initializing your ArrayList? I'm more familiar with Kotlin so in my code I would write:

```
var questionList : ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
```

This looks like it's an error coming from your code and not from Firestore...otherwise you would see something Firestore related in the error.

Comment: So I don't really know Kotlin ... but I used 'ArrayList<String> questions;'  Therefore I just created the array list before the onCreate method and then after calling my get_questions() Function it should add strings to the arrayList. but it seems like it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the .getResult() while looping the document.

Try the following code:

```
public void get_questions(){
    ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();

    colref_QUESTIONS.get()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

            for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots.getResult()){
                String question = documentSnapshot.getString("question");
                String answer = documentSnapshot.getString("answer");
                questions.add(question);
                answers.add(answer);
                nrofquestions++;
            }
        }  
    });
```

}